Carmichael Numbers sample test data
I need some  set of Carmichael numbers as test data especially of 1024, 2048, 3072 and 4096 bits.
On my laptop, I'm doing the following to find such data set.

Generate $k$ of the size of $n^{1/3}$
Compute $(6k+1)(12k+1)(18k+1)$
Check if the outcome of step to 2 is prime using MR test; if yes, then it's a Carmichael number.

It's been 12 hours; so far no luck. If there is any standard source from which I can take the Carmichael numbers of size 1024, 2048, 3072 and 4096 bits can you please let me know.

Are you content with concrete examples ? With some suitable tool , as PARI/GP , you can compute the desired Carmichael numbers for yourself. You may need some patience since ALL factors must be prime.

Thank you, not aware of PARI/GP was looking into it, it really helps.

$(6k+1)(12k+1)(18k+1)$ is obviously never a prime, so your step 3 should say something like "I run the MR test" because you're really not checking if it is a prime...

You can look here: https://github.com/drazioti/Carmichael/tree/master/Tables

Right, my initial intention was to construct weak RSA keys, so to generate some composite numbers that pass MR. Though with that approach I got the number that passed MR for certain random bases. Later I realized that it can be the case for any composite number. Thanks for the gitlink it was helpful.

Note that
$(6k+1)(12k+1)(18k+1)$
is never prime. You want to check if each of the factors is prime.
Here’s some PARI/GP code to generate a Carmichael number of the desired form larger than a given bound.
do(x)=my(t=sqrtn(x\=1,3)); t=ceil(solve(y=t/11-1,t/10, (6*y+1)*(12*y+1)*(18*y+1)-x-.5)); forprimestep(p=18*t+1,oo,18, my(k=p\18); if(isprime(6*k+1) && isprime(12*k+1), return((6*k+1)*(12*k+1)*p)))
do(10^1023)
do(10^2047)
do(19^3071)
do(10^4095)

You can find Carmichael numbers with less effort by making them with many primes instead of just 3; there are many papers (see for example [1][2][3]) that construct gigantic Carmichael numbers in this fashion. To do this efficiently, you're going to want to sieve for candidates (or sieve them completely, if the primes to be generated are sufficiently small).

Ming Zhi Zhang, A method for finding large Carmichael numbers, Sichuan Daxue Xuebao 29 (1992), no. 4, pp. 472–479.
Günter Löh & Wolfgang Niebuhr, A new algorithm for constructing large Carmichael numbers, Mathematics of Computation, Volume 65, Number 214, April 1996, pp. 823–836.
W.R. Alford, Jon Grantham, Steven Hayman, & Andrew Shallue, Constructing Carmichael numbers through improved subset-product algorithms, Mathematics of Computation, Volume 83, Number 286, March 2014, pp. 899–915. See also Constructing a ten billion factor Carmichael number which is a poster version of this paper.


What does its solving $(6y+1)(12y+1)(18*y+1)-x-.5)$? If possible can you please elaborate your approach using math equations instead of this pari/gp script.

@sg777 solving (6y+1)(12y+1)(18y+1)-x = 0 gives the value of y such that (6y+1)(12y+1)(18y+1) = x. Since x should be an integer, solving for 0.5 less lets me dispense with a certain about of error checking when using floating point calculations.

im able to generate Carmichael numbers, tried generating 1024 bit numbers and i see them in 1-2 minutes. Still couldn't understand this part of the above equation $y=t/11-1,t/10$, will go through references and revert, thank you.

@sg777 Just some quick bounds on the root of the equation.
